# WebScrapy Scrapy python, no insertar None/Null al csv

Tags: python, scrapy, web-scrapping

Hola buenos días comunidad,

Elabore un webscrapy con scrapy, extrae los comentarios de un cierto hotel pero hay comentarios que no me trae el review solo el nombre pero se repite en cada salto de página, hay alguna manera de que cuando detecte que el review venga vacio no me lo inserte en el csv?. Comparto codigo y ejemplo

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class Review(Item):
   user = Field()
   review = Field()
   estadia = Field()

class TripAdvisor(CrawlSpider):
   name = "Review"
   custom_settings = {
      "user-agent": "Chrome/71.0.3578.80",
      'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 50
   }

   allowed_domains = ['tripadvisor.com.mx']
   start_urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.com.mx/Hotel_Review-g150807-d634235-Reviews- 
                    Seadust_Cancun_Family_Resort-Cancun_Yucatan_Peninsula.html']
   download_delay = 2    

   rules = (
       Rule(
           LinkExtractor(
               allow = r'-or\d+-'            
           ), follow=True, callback='parse_seadust'
       ),  
   )



   def parse_seadust(self,response ): 
       sel = Selector(response)
       review = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "YibKl MC R2 Gi z Z BB pBbQr")]')
       for personrw in review:
              item = ItemLoader(Review(), personrw)
              item.add_xpath('review', './/div[contains(@class, "WAllg _T")]/div[contains(@class, "vTVDc")]/div[contains(@class, "_T FKffI bmUTE")]/div[contains(@class, "fIrGe _T")]/q/span/text()')
            item.add_xpath('estadia', './/div[contains(@class, "WAllg _T")]/div[contains(@class, "vTVDc")]/div[contains(@class, "EftBQ")]/span[@class="teHYY _R Me S4 H3"]/text()')
            item.add_xpath('user', './/div[@class="cRVSd"]/span/a/text()')
            yield item.load_item()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]